# Is it possible to build a Monotouch application in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.ios

I would like to know if it is possible to compile a Monotouch project that does not have any reference to any UI library in Visual Studio. This project only use the Monotouch framework.

I have done some research and I read that, if the project don't have any reference to the Apple SDK , I should be able to build a MonoTouch project using Visual Studio.  If I  can, do i need some particular configuration to achive my goal.

Some related links:
[How easy is it to develop an iPhone application using MonoTouch in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695149/how-easy-is-it-to-develop-an-iphone-application-using-monotouch-in-visual-studio),
[How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine#28573),
[iPhone development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if your project doesn't have any references to MonoTouch libraries, it is still a MonoTouch library project. Visual studio doesn't recognize that project type and because of that you can't really compile the code.

I wrote about this a while ago, and how you can change your project so you can actually use Visual Studio for development (although you won't be able to run the app) here: 
http://escoz.com/blog/developing-with-monotouch-on-windows-and-visual-studio

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @bigwave, its working again, I was updating the blog.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Visual Studio addin that may help. It hasn't been updated in a while though.  Also, this would only help you write the code. To compile and run the code, you will still need MonoTouch and a Mac.  https://github.com/follesoe/VSMonoTouch

Update : As of February, 2013 Xamarin includes Visual Studio support for developing iOS apps in their Business sku of Xamarin.iOS.  You can fully develop on Windows + Visual Studio, but still need a Mac on your network to perform builds and run the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about building a DLL or library in VS.NET that you could then use in a MonoTouch project, I believe the answer is NO.  To be usable in MT, the code has to be compiled with MT.

Answer (score 0):

The MonoDevAssist VS extension (search VS Extension Manager for "monotouch") seems to work perfectly.  There are just a couple of easy steps to follow post-installation, which are documented here:

http://monodevassist.codeplex.com/documentation